# Android localization: Some strings are not translated to Spanish Lang

Tags: java, android, localization, translation

I have a `string` file in Spanish Lang. When i change device language  to Spanish , some `strings` are translated and some remains in default English Language. Below is my code.

I have added this line in manifest file `android:configChanges="locale"`

```
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        Ut.refreshLayoutAccordingToLanguage(BaseActivity.this);
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

public static void refreshLayoutAccordingToLanguage(Activity mContext) {
        try {
            String lang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
            Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
            Resources res = mContext.getResources();
            DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
            Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
            conf.locale = myLocale;
            res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
            mContext.onConfigurationChanged(conf);
}
```

and then I restart my activity like this

```
Intent intent = mContext.getIntent();
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            mContext.finish();
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Please help.

Comment: @Prem yes I restart activity

Comment: share your code where you are change the locale